Construct 4 letter code made from letters A-Z, no consecutive letters
Hi I would like to solve this problem with this approach:
(All combinations) - (Ones with a repeat)
I've identified these forms of repeats
AAXX (26 * 1 * 25 * 25)
XAAX (26 * 25 * 1 * 25)
XXAA (26 * 25 * 25 * 1)
AAAX (26 * 1 * 1 * 25)
XAAA (26 * 25 * 1 * 1)
AAAA (26 * 1 * 1 * 1)
So when I subtract everything
All combinations (26^4) - the above total
(26^4) - 3(26 * 25 * 25) - 2(26*25)-1(26) = 406,900
But the actual solution is 406,250 = 26 * 25 * 25*25
Where is my miscalculation?

It's much simpler than that. The first letter can be one of $26$ letters and the second letter can be one of $25$ letters, the third letter can be one of $25$ different from the second, and fourth again one of $25$ different from the first/ this gives $26\cdot25^3.$

Yep! I was wondering where in my approach things went off.

You'overcounted examples like $AABB.$ Yo've counted this example once in $AAXX$ and once in $XXAA$]

If you want to fix it, $XYAA$ and $AAXY$ should get $26\cdot25^2$ assuming that X and Y must be different, but Y can be A. In addition,there are those those of the form $AABB,$ and there are $26\cdot25$ of those

So I was wrong about over counting. You undercounted the number you are subtracting. You either over-counted AABB and failed to count AABA, or you failed to count any AABB.$ Either way, you've missed  more than you've overcounted.

The problem is with the AAXX and XXAA cases. You don't say what the $26\cdot25\cdot25$ counts in this case, but it seems you are likely either:

Including cases AAXA, in which case you are missing the examples of the form AABB.
Counting the cases AABB twice, once in each of the two subsets, but not counting the words of the form AABA or ABAA.

In either case, you need to subtract an additional $26\cdot25=2\cdot26\cdot25-25\cdot25.$
If you want to be extra careful, you can use inclusion-exclusion.
Let $W$ be the set of all four-letter words, and $W_i$ the subset of words where the the $i$th letter and the $i+1$st letters are the same. Then we want $|W\setminus (W_1\cup W_2\cup W_3)|$ which inclusion-exclusion counts this as $$|W|-|W_1|-|W_2|-|W_3|+|W_1\cap W_2|+|W_2\cap W_3|+|W_1\cap W _3|-|W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3|\\=26^4-3\cdot26^3+3\cdot 26^2-26=26\cdot(26-1)^3$$
